# where is spfile of +ASM?

Tags: oracle

I cannot find spfile of ASM instance.

1. show parameter spfile does not return any value
2. $ORACLE_HOME/dbs does not contain any spfile
3. asmcmd does not show even directory /DATA/+ASM
4. create pfile from spfile return error ORA-01565: error in identifying file status

I am able to stop/start +ASM instance. Other databases uses ASM so everything seems to be ok except ..... there is no spfile :(
The most interesting is lack of directory /DATA/+ASM . I am pretty sure it was it a few days ago.

Comment: What does the [`asmcmd` command `spget`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e18951/asm_util002.htm#OSTMG94426) show you? (And won't the directory be /DATA/ASM, without the +?)

Comment: ASMCMD> spget
+DATA/asm/asmparameterfile/registry.253.894717045
ASMCMD>
but directory +DATA/asm not exists or I just don't see it

Comment: So have you deleted the ASM directory from within asmcmd? If you have a pfile under $ORACLE_HOME/dbs maybe it's starting from that instead - not something I want to experiment with right now.

Comment: hmmm ... it seems it is possible to start +ASM without spfile. 
ORA-00099: warning: no parameter file specified for ASM instance  ASM instance started
(.....)
ORA-15110: no diskgroups mounted

Comment: This really depends on Oracle version. Each release does it differently. What is your Oracle version?

Comment: ok, it is going to be more clear now.   I had to erase this file/directory( completely don't know how) anyway , instance starts without spfile but  then I need to up diskgroups. Then it is fully functional.